# Break at first line for JavaScript in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to figure out the place where certain action takes place in JS spaghetti code.

I got JetBrains IDE Support plugin set and running and it reacts nicely on each breakpoint I define. But what I would like it to do instead is break/stop at the first line of JavaScript code when I click on a button or do anything else that involves some JS processing.

If that is not possible than how can figure out what is being called after I perform certain action on a website?

Comment: This is almost unanswerable.. What kind of javascript ? Web-based ? You could just open chrome console and hit (f8) for example to `break-all`.. What exactly do you mean ? `break/stop at the first line of javascript code when I click on a button or do anything else that involves some JS processing` why not just add the breakpoint ?

Chrome's developer console will show you a stack trace and will show you the network requests etc..

Comment: I am not sure how PHP Storm integrates with the Browser, but I use Chrome and its developer tools to debug JS. Works like a charm.

Comment: I would try to use browser script console and add breakpoints where needed. This way you have current variable values shown and you can even manage them

Comment: I know those tools but like I have said earlier the code is a complete mess. Therefor I'm looking for a way to stop execution at the first JavaScript line when action gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know where to put the breakpoint, you might try a bit different approach to debugging using spy-js. You need to install spy-js plugin in PhpStorm preferences. It traces your app and shows all the events that are triggered. That might help you to understand where you can then put the breakpoint. 
You can find more info about spy-js here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/04/spy-js-webstorm-secret-service/

Answer (score 0):

You can take this [free codeschool course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools) on devtools to improve your knowledge in debugging. It's free and takes just a few hours.